# how are user ids assigned to new users?

Tags: users

what determines what user id to which a new user account will be assigned? On my site, Drupal 7.37, new user accounts are assigned to non-sequential user ids. All new users now have user ids well above 3500.

Comment: You already asked this question 3 days ago. Instead of asking it again, read the feedback and update the previous question: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/223701/9921

Comment: The titles are very similar @Neograph734 but the ultimate questions are different (_what determines what user id to which a new user account will be assigned?_ and _how can I ensure that new user ids do not exceed the value that causes the user account to get blocked?_). The original one is (probably fairly) closed as too broad as there are dozens of combinations of things that could make that happen...this one does have a definitive answer

Comment: @clive fair enough :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of layers here...

Any code that calls [`user_save`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_save/7.x) can technically affect what ID is assigned. If the account object has a uid property, that is used, otherwise it comes from the database:

```
// Allow 'uid' to be set by the caller. There is no danger of writing an
// existing user as drupal_write_record will do an INSERT.
if (empty($account->uid)) {
  $account->uid = db_next_id(db_query('SELECT MAX(uid) FROM {users}')->fetchField());
}
```

So if an ID is provided, great, if not (which is the norm), it gets more complicated.

The `users` table doesn't have an auto-increment column (probably because an ID of 0 is used for the anonymous user, and there's no way to support that across all DB platforms). If you were to just get the last inserted user ID + 1, you're open to race conditions when other requests get the same ID returned before the first script has had a chance to insert the record into `users`.

Because of that, the Sequence API is used. The `sequences` table has a single, auto-incremented primary key column. When a new, unique, identifier is required, a record is inserted into that table, and the auto-assigned ID is returned to Drupal. That ensures it's not susceptible to race conditions, as the operation has already completed and any other requests would be guaranteed a new ID.

If you just need to hack around the problem you mentioned, and you're not worried about or prepared to take the risk of race conditions, add this to a custom module:

```
function MYMODULE_user_presave(&$edit, $account, $category) {
  if (!empty($account->is_new)) {
    $account->uid = db_query('SELECT MAX(uid) FROM {users}')->fetchField() + 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: this seems pretty convoluted - especially when I follow the code and documentation and there is something about the 'sequence' table.  I am not at clear what the LOGIC is that determines how the "next" user id should be chosen.  Why is not simply one more than the highest existing user id??

Comment: It's convoluted because it's solving quite a complex problem - `sequences` contains surrogate primary keys for tables, like `users`, that don't have an auto-increment column. (Drupal uses an ID of 0 for the anonymous user, which isn't a valid identifier in some/all engines and you'd be encouraging race conditions by simply selecting the highest ID + 1). By inserting a new record into that table every time, and returning _its_ primary key, you're guaranteed an identifier that will be unique throughout the system, as long as all interaction with the table(s) in question uses the same method

Comment: That's why you get jumps in the user ids btw, something else is using the sequence table too. I'll consolidate that into a better answer, two ticks

Comment: I had been hoping to get  control of the value for the next user id as a temporary workaround to the real problem I am having where accounts with user ids higher than some value (I have not yet pinned down the boundary value) are getting blocked by something I have not yet identified... presumably by some module, but it seems odd for some random module to decide to block a user account based on its id exceeding some value. It sounds like I will not be able to get control of the user ids and therefor, will not be able to use that as a temporary workaround.

Comment: Getting control of it's easy enough, I updated the answer with an example

Comment: As this will be (I hope) a temporary hack until I can figure out what is blocking accounts with 'high' use ids, it is probably easier to patch the user module than to write a new custom module. It would seem that I could just replace 

$account->uid = db_next_id(db_query('SELECT MAX(uid) FROM {users}')->fetchField());] 

with 

 $account->uid = db_query('SELECT MAX(uid) FROM {users}')->fetchField() + 1;

thank you